# MySQL result combination

Tags: mysql

I am fairly new to MySQL and I am having a bit of a problem trying to combine a few queries into a single one.  Basically I have two tables:

I need to get:

- ALL IDJobs where StaffID is NOT Part of it
- ALL IDJobs where StaffID is part of it AND has a Status 1 or 6

.

```
Jobs
------------------
IDJob   - The PKey
JobInfo - Some Data

JobPosition
------------------
PositionID - Each Job can have multiple positions
JobID      - Value from Jobs Table
StaffID    - Value from Staffs Table
Status     - Status of Staff for the Job
```

I am trying to get all IDJobs WHERE

```
(
    SELECT JobID AS IDJob
    FROM SelectedStaff
    WHERE StaffID <>10
)
UNION 
(
    SELECT IDJob
    FROM Jobs
    WHERE IDJob
    IN (
            SELECT JobID
            FROM SelectedStaff
            WHERE SelectStatus
            IN ( 1, 6 )
            AND StaffID =10
       )
)
```

But the result is not returning for me the Job IDs where the Staff is not part of it.  That would be the bigger list, and then filtering it with the smaller query.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Sample data would be:

```
Jobs Table
IDJob           JobInfo
1               Job1
2               Job2
3               Job3
```

.

```
JobPosition
PositionID      JobID      StaffID      Status
1               2          10           0
2               2          10           6
3               3          10           0
```

This should result:

```
IDJob
1
2
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select jp.JobId
from JobPosition jp
group by jp.JobId
having sum(StaffId = 10) = 0 or -- Staff10 is not part of the job
       sum(StaffId = 10 and status in (1, 6)) > 0
```

This uses conditional aggregation in the `where` clause to count the number of rows that match each of your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solution that finally worked for me. I don't know if I am making it too complicated, but it is the right result:

```
(
    SELECT IDJob 
    FROM Jobs 
    WHERE IDJob 
    NOT IN (
                  SELECT JobID AS IDJob 
                  FROM JobPosition 
                  WHERE StaffID = 10
           )
) 
UNION
(
    SELECT IDJob 
    FROM Jobs 
    WHERE IDJob 
    IN (
           SELECT JobID 
           FROM SelectedStaff 
           WHERE JobPosition IN (1,6) 
           AND StaffID=10
        )
)
```